Failure in VS Code Pester extension when refreshing the tests
I am using VS Code for my PowerShell development. I have version 5.1 of PowerShell and version 1.95.3 of VS Code. I have the Pester extension installed in VS Code (version v2023.7.7). Until recently, I've had no issue with this extension but in the last few days whenever I try to refresh my Pester tests in VS Code I get the popup with the error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controllerId').
When I check the logs in the extension host output of VS Code I can see the error message
2024-11-26 09:57:48.939 [error] Error: [ExtensionListenerError] Extension 'pspester.pester-test' FAILED to handle event: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testFilePatterns')
    at mh.value (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:156:35379)
    at D.B (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:746)
    at D.C (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:816)
    at D.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:1033)
    at mh.value (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:137:104121)
    at D.B (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:746)
    at D.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:964)
    at Sw.acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:121:11444)
    at Sw.$acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:121:10040)
    at py.S (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:113311)
    at py.Q (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:113091)
    at py.M (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:112180)
    at py.L (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:111285)
    at mh.value (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:110082)
    at D.B (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:746)
    at D.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:964)
    at Vn.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:9457)
    at mh.value (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:174:13300)
    at D.B (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:746)
    at D.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:29:964)
    at Vn.fire (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:9457)
    at MessagePortMain.<anonymous> (file:///c:/Users/mchaleg/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:174:11592)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2949)

I also noticed that if I try to run the tests after getting the error message above, the tests will run but I get some strange errors that don't make any sense (e.g. functions not available for imported modules and directories not available even though they exist on the local machine).
If I run the Pester tests from the command line, they pass without any problems, which suggests that the problem is not in the Pester tests but in the VS Code extension.
I have tried:

Restarting VS Code
Reinstalling the Pester extension
Disabling all other extensions
Reverting my code to an old version where I never saw the problem occur

I don't know how to proceed so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please report an issue in the repo https://github.com/pester/vscode-adapter and we'll look at it. Do you have a workspace open when this happens or just a empty vscode windows with a single file? Does it work in another folder/workspace?

Thanks @FrodeF. I have submitted the issue (see https://github.com/pester/vscode-adapter/issues/279).

I am not using any VS Code workspaces. The test files live within a sub-folder of my project folder
The same problem is happening in different projects These other projects are set up the same way (i.e. PowerShell and Pester files within a project folder).

I have included this information in the submitted ticket.
